# Interferes with the general style of the body tag on the style of the modal window

Tags: css

I have a modal window and styles for it. It is called when the local guard already has such a phone number and the user sends the same number from the form. On some sites, when a modal window is open, you cannot scroll the page, now I am faced with the fact that on one of the sites where I am testing my code, you can scroll the page when the modal window is made. I found the reason. There is a style in the badi tag (code below) that prevents it from working correctly; if you turn it off via F12, scrolling will be blocked. That is, as I understand it, these styles prevent the styles for my modal window from working. How can I solve this problem?

Body:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

My style for modal window:

```
#mmyMModal {
  all: initial;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  animation: fadeIn 0.2s ease;
}

  #mmyMModal .mmodal-ccontent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 20px; /* Используем пиксели для конкретного размера */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 80%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

  #mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow {
  color: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

  #mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow:hover,
  #mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  #mmyMModal .mmodal-ttext {
  all: initial;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

  #mmyMModal .success_icon {
  all: initial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

  #mmyMModal .success_icon p {
  all: initial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  animation: iconScale 0.2s ease;
}

  #mmyMModal .success_icon p::before {
  all: initial;
  content: "";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

  #mmyMModal .success_icon p::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ef2c2c;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Адаптивные стили для модального окна */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#mmyMModal .mmodal-ccontent {
  padding: 30px; /* Используем пиксели для конкретного размера */
  font-size: 16px;
}

#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow {
  font-size: 24px;
  top: 5px; /* Используем пиксели для конкретного отступа */
  right: 5px; /* Используем пиксели для конкретного отступа */
}

#mmyMModal .success_icon p {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
from {
  opacity: 0;
}
to {
  opacity: 1;
}
}

@keyframes iconScale {
0% {
  transform: scale(0);
}
50% {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
100% {
  transform: scale(1);
}
}

  body.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
  }`;
```

Modal window:

```
 const modalHTML = `
<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div id="mmyMModal" class="mmodalWWindow">
<div class="mmodal-ccontent">
  <p id="eerror-ttitle" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
  <div class="success_icon">
    <p class="closeIcon">X</p>
  </div>
  <span class="ccloseWWindow">&times;</span>
  <p id="mmodalTText" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
</div>
</div>
`;

    // Функция для расчета размера Local Storage
    function calculateLocalStorageSize() {
      let totalSize = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        let key = localStorage.key(i);
        let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        totalSize += (key.length + value.length) * 2;
      }

      // Конвертируем в КБ для удобства
      let totalSizeKB = totalSize / 1024;

      return totalSizeKB.toFixed(2);
    }

    document.head.appendChild(modalStyle);
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', modalHTML);

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var icon = document.querySelector('#mmyMModal .success_icon p');
      if (icon) {
        icon.addEventListener('click', function () {
          icon.style.animation = 'iconScale 0.5s ease';
          setTimeout(function () {
            icon.style.animation = '';
          }, 500);
        });
      }

      function showModal(errorMessage, errorTitle) {
        var modal = document.getElementById('mmyMModal');
        var errorTitleElement = document.getElementById('eerror-ttitle');
        var modalTextElement = document.getElementById('mmodalTText');

        errorTitle = errorTitle.trim();
        errorMessage = errorMessage.trim();
        errorTitleElement.textContent = errorTitle;
        modalTextElement.textContent = errorMessage;

        modal.style.display = "block";

        var span = document.querySelector("#mmyMModal .ccloseWWindow");
        span.onclick = function () {
          modal.style.display = "none";
          document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        }

        window.onclick = function (event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
          }
        }
        document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
      }

      function checkPhoneNumber(event) {
        var form = event.target; 
        var offer = form.querySelector('input[name="offer"]').value; 
        var phone = form.querySelector('input[name="phone"]').value; 
        var country = form.querySelector('input[name="country_code"]').value; /

        // Получаем данные из LocalStorage
        var storagePhone = localStorage.getItem('storagePhone');
        if (!storagePhone) {
          storagePhone = {};
        } else {
          storagePhone = JSON.parse(storagePhone);
        }


        if (storagePhone.hasOwnProperty(offer) && storagePhone[offer].includes(phone)) {
          var errorMessage, errorTitle;
          switch (country.toUpperCase()) {
            case 'AL':
              errorTitle = "Gabim";
              errorMessage = "Më vjen keq, keni dërguar tashmë një kërkesë."; 
              break;
            default:
              errorTitle = "Error";
              errorMessage = "Sorry, you have already submitted an inquiry."; 
          }
          showModal(errorMessage, errorTitle);
          return false; 
        }


        if (!storagePhone.hasOwnProperty(offer)) {
          storagePhone[offer] = [];
        }
        storagePhone[offer].push(phone);


        localStorage.setItem('storagePhone', JSON.stringify(storagePhone));

        return true;
      }


      var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');


      forms.forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          if (!checkPhoneNumber(event)) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
          }
        });
      });
    });
    var localStorageSizeKB = calculateLocalStorageSize();
    console.log("Размер Local Storage: " + localStorageSizeKB + " KB");
  </script>
```

I tried the all property unset and initial which breaks the badi styles, but still scrolling the page is possible.

Comment: Pls provide us with your HTML code